# How to use or annotate a dummy field in a JPA entity bean which is not supposed to be persisted in database

Tags: java, orm, jpa

I have this code for login validation using a Struts2 action class which calls an EJB for LDAP validation and then if (LDAP credentials) validated, querying the user database to get the rest of the user information using the JPA entity bean which also acts like a POJO. Unlike the username, userid and other user info, password is not stored in the database, but for the sake of the POJO getter and setter method I attempt to include a dummy password field - for serving the Struts2 action form.

The problem is after ldap authentication, an exception occurs stating that the column "password" does not exist in the database (which was never meant to be anyway!)

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'PASSWORD' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT PERSON_ID, ACTIVE_USER, EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME, EMPLOYEE_NUMBER FROM xxte_employees WHERE (ACTIVE_USER = ?)
        bind => [john.doe]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="XxteEmployees.validateLogin" referenceClass=XxteEmployees sql="SELECT PERSON_ID, ACTIVE_USER, EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, PASSWORD, FULLNAME, EMPLOYEE_NUMBER FROM xxte_employees WHERE (ACTIVE_USER = ?)")
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:687)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:529)
....
```

Here's the code from the entity bean:

```
public class XxteEmployees implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE_USER")
    private String activeUser;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Double personId;
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
    private Double employeeNumber;
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;

    private String fullname;

    private String password;

    public XxteEmployees() {
    }

    public XxteEmployees(Double personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getActiveUser() {
        return activeUser;
    }

    public void setActiveUser(String activeUser) {
        this.activeUser = activeUser;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Double getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(Double personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public Double getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(Double employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }


    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    // BEGIN: objects not in db

    public String getFullname() {
        return firstname + ' ' + surname;
    }


    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = firstname + ' ' + surname;;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return sifre;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    // END: objects not in db
```

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Annotate any fields that you don't want to be persisted as `@Transient`. It is in the `javax.persistence` package.